# Javascript print out

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am currently using thins easy function to print out the whole page.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();" ><img src="print1.jpg" border="0" alt="In"></a>
```

But there is some stuff that I want to put out. Is there any way to not to printout some html from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

You can make a special CSS file that hides stuff that you do not need on the printed page, or you can even style some stuff diferently.

Once you have that just include that CSS file in your HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

The browser will then apply this style sheet to your HTML when printing (and only then).

You can also read [this excellent article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) from A List Apart on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Add a print style sheet to the page. In it you can hide ceratin element with disply:none;

[www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)